# How can I implement a php tag and echo within another php tag and echo?

Tags: php, session

Basically what I want is when the if statement doesn't return as empty and it runs the 2nd echo I also want to echo $_SESSION variables within that echo.

```
    <?php 

    $gallerystatus = $_SESSION['u_gallerypicture'];


    if(empty($gallerystatus)){

     echo'<p> No posts uploaded yet... To add a photo click the New Post button.</p>';

    }
    else{
    echo'
    <!-- Main container -->
    <div id="content-container">
    <div class="gallery group">
        <div class="grid">
            <a href="#">
                <img height="216.66" src=" <?php echo "../image-gallery-upload/images/" . $_SESSION["u_gallerypicture"]; ?> ">
                <span><?php echo $_SESSION["u_caption"]; ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>';}?>
```

Comment: Do all session arrays have value?

Comment: Did you close off the `else` with `}`? I don't see it.

Comment: Use "." to concatenate strings.

Comment: tip, if your about to echo a huge chunk of HTML simply break out of php, code looks cleaner and your editor can pick up on syntax highlight/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 

$gallerystatus = $_SESSION['u_gallerypicture'];


if(empty($gallerystatus)){

 echo'<p> No posts uploaded yet... To add a photo click the New Post button.</p>';

}
else{
echo'
<!-- Main container -->
<div id="content-container">
<div class="gallery group">
    <div class="grid">
        <a href="#">
            <img height="216.66" src="../image-gallery-upload/images/"' . $_SESSION["u_gallerypicture"] . '">
            <span> ' . $_SESSION["u_caption"] . '</span>
        </a>
    </div>';?>
```

Just try to concatenate it. You never need to open PHP tag before closing it.

Comment: Your code doesn't work

Comment: Just updated, I didnt saw the second PHP tag

Comment: In the same way, please check the answer.  And please read the official documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php